# Getting "Forbidden: null" in my Node.js application when trying to access files from my S3 bucket

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3

This is an issue I've encountered in the last couple of days in my Node.js application. I am running aws-sdk version 2.272.1.

The error comes from the function s3.headObject. I am not sure if it relates to the access and secret keys not being configured properly or something else but I've unable to fix this issue.

```
let awsParams = { Bucket: generic-bucket-name, Key: req.params.profile_image_unique_id };
    return s3.headObject(awsParams, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        return res.status(400).send({
             error_title: 'File failed to download, unknown error',
             error_message: 'File failed to download, unknown error'
        });
    }

        let stream = s3.getObject(awsParams).createReadStream();

        // forward errors
        stream.on('error', function error(err) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                error_title: 'File failed to download, unknown error',
                error_message: 'File failed to download, unknown error'
            });
        });

        res.set('Content-Type', mime.getType('.jpeg'));
        res.set('Content-Length', data.ContentLength);
        res.set('Last-Modified', data.LastModified);
        res.set('ETag', data.ETag);
        res.status(200);

        stream.pipe(res);
    });
```

This is the error I get when calling the s3.headObject function. The error message is not that helpful besides telling me that I have no access to the files stored in my s3 bucket.

```
{
Forbidden: null
at Request.extractError (C:\Users\johnn\Documents\juristerra-v3\Express\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\services\s3.js:798:35)
at Request.callListeners (C:\Users\johnn\Documents\juristerra-v3\Express\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:106:20)
at Request.emit (C:\Users\johnn\Documents\juristerra-v3\Express\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:78:10)
at Request.emit (C:\Users\johnn\Documents\juristerra-v3\Express\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:683:14)
at Request.transition (C:\Users\johnn\Documents\juristerra-v3\Express\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:22:10)
at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (C:\Users\johnn\Documents\juristerra-v3\Express\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\state_machine.js:14:12)
at C:\Users\johnn\Documents\juristerra-v3\Express\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\state_machine.js:26:10
at Request. (C:\Users\johnn\Documents\juristerra-v3\Express\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:38:9)
at Request. (C:\Users\johnn\Documents\juristerra-v3\Express\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:685:12)
at Request.callListeners (C:\Users\johnn\Documents\juristerra-v3\Express\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:116:18)
at Request.emit (C:\Users\johnn\Documents\juristerra-v3\Express\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:78:10)
at Request.emit (C:\Users\johnn\Documents\juristerra-v3\Express\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:683:14)
at Request.transition (C:\Users\johnn\Documents\juristerra-v3\Express\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:22:10)
at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (C:\Users\johnn\Documents\juristerra-v3\Express\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\state_machine.js:14:12)
at C:\Users\johnn\Documents\juristerra-v3\Express\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\state_machine.js:26:10
at Request. (C:\Users\johnn\Documents\juristerra-v3\Express\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:38:9)
at Request. (C:\Users\johnn\Documents\juristerra-v3\Express\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:685:12)
at Request.callListeners (C:\Users\johnn\Documents\juristerra-v3\Express\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:116:18)
at callNextListener (C:\Users\johnn\Documents\juristerra-v3\Express\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:96:12)
at IncomingMessage.onEnd (C:\Users\johnn\Documents\juristerra-v3\Express\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\event_listeners.js:307:13)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:203:15)
at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
message: null,
code: 'Forbidden',
region: null,
time: 2019-12-26T20:42:02.817Z,
requestId: '15B13D1F7B4432A3',
extendedRequestId:
'+0xHIoU3OZ7RoLBJFKp0CO6VO9qNet0g1gyPBoBUfTuboTa9f6FIHXA0/A+5wjYpLnpTFH4J5/8=',
cfId: undefined,
statusCode: 403,
retryable: false,
retryDelay: 55.89876980791042
}
```

Have any of you encountered an issue like this before?

Answer (score 1):

This issue is a permission issue. There can be two things to check here.

- s3:GetObject - permission
- s3:ListBucket - permission

For more information please read the documentation link below
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-403-forbidden-error/

Comment: but what specifically do you put the permission on? I'm getting the same error when doing a web-initiated call through the gateway api to a lambda function using a temporary sts token. The sts token has permission to execute the gatewayapi proxy call. Do I have to give lambda permissions on the sts token  or do I give it to something tied to the gateway api or something else entirely?

Comment: oh, and btw, the temporary sts token has specific permissions to run the lambda function in question already as well as filtered S3 access (prefix filter for user files) for the files being manipulated in two different buckets.

Answer (score 0):

The lambda can be granted permission to access s3 bucket using it's IAM role.

Here is how you configure the IAM role for lambda.

Reference:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-execution-role-s3-bucket/

Also you don't need `return` infront of `s3.getObject` if you are not using the promise syntax

Answer (score 0):

The Secret Access Key which you are using needs to have proper IAM policies attached to it while performing any operations.